# What is wrong with this recorded macro?

Tags: vba

I have just started learning VBA and I have tried to record a macro to see How Excel works. I recorded a simple task :

1. I copied the range A1:D1001 in a sheet
2. I created a pivot table from it
3. I added a row field and a value

When I stopped the recording and tried to run the macro, I received the following error message:

"Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument"

I don't understand how it could happen since Excel itself wrote this macro.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:D1001").Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Moz Keyword Explorer 'diy beaut!L1C1:L1001C4", Version:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Feuil1!L3C1", _
        TableName:="Tableau croisé dynamique1", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Feuil1").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique1").PivotFields("Keyword" _
        )
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique1").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
        PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique1").PivotFields("Max Volume"), _
        "NB sur Max Volume", xlCount
    ExecuteExcel4Macro _
        "PIVOT.FIELD.PROPERTIES(""Tableau croisé dynamique1"",""NB sur Max Volume"",,,2)"
End Sub
```

Comment: At just a glace, I'd imagine it's because the `TableName` is hard-coded. Is the error on the `ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create` line?

Comment: Yes it is in that line, but why is the fact that the TableNAme hardcoded a bad thing?

Comment: Agree with @Comintern, but you'd also get that error if your computer didn't recognise the L1C1 notation. For example, English settings would need the notation as R1C1. So if you've used the code on a different computer, this error could occur. As a test, try changing your cell references to absolute, eg "A1:D1001" for "L1C1:L1001C4" and "A3" for "L3C1".

Comment: dont do step 1. simply open a new worksheet, then select create pivot table. It will prompt you to select the range you want in your table. Do that via the record macro and it should work

Comment: I tried Ambie and mo.h's solutions but it still doesn't work, I guess I'll have to study more about pivot tables and VBA to be able to fix it at some point.